# Throws own exception from validate in android simple framework

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I am using [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) in my project and have following problem

#### Source code

```
@Root (name = "Test")
@Order (elements = { "UserName", .... })
public class Test
{

    @Element
    public String UserName;

    @Validate
    public void validate() throws Exception
    {
        if(UserName.length() > 10) {
            throw new Exception("User ID is invalid");
        }
    }
};
```

In the main code I write something like this

```
try {
     serializer.read(REQ.class, reader);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
     Log.i(TAG, ex.getMessage()); <--- HERE I GET MESSAGE: null, not the one I throws.
}
```

#### Question

Look like I can't catch exception which I throws, like validate function get my exception and replace it with it's own one. So am I right and what I can do to throw my own exception?

Comment: Have you checked ex.getCause?  It's quite likely that the SimpleXML parser wrapped your exception in one of its own.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike and if its so, how I can change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you G.BlakeMeike you were right, the solution is follow:

```
try {
     serializer.read(REQ.class, reader);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
     Log.i(TAG, ex.getCause().getMessage());
}
```